# different resources for different screen size android app

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am developing an andriod app using eclipse. I have the following folder structure.

Xml file folder:

```
/res/layout
/res/layout-large
/res/layout-large-mdpi
/res/layout-mdpi
/res/layout
/res/layout-xlarge
```

Image folder:

```
/res/drawable
/res/drawable-hdpi
/res/drawable-ldpi
/res/drawable-mdpi
/res/drawable-xhdpi
/res/drawable-xxhdpi
```

I have used this code in my manifest.xml

```
 <supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" />
```

I have a logo image of different sizes in the drawable folders. But now all my layout.xml using the image from  `/res/drawable-mdpi` only. How to fix this?

Comment: What's your target SDK version in manifest?

Comment: target SDK version is 18

Comment: how did you verify it uses the mdpi version ? Are you talking about a full screen images ? your question isn't really clear. please add at least two different layout xmls, their containing folder and the result you would expect.

Comment: have you tried to Clean your project ?

Answer (score -1):

**Check(TEST) this before you try!!!**

This is not perfect answer for your Question, But this is a chance if you have minimum number of Images in your app:

[Go through the developer site here :](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)

and read complete details,

For better results on your app consider 1,2 points before "**Using configuration qualifiers**" paragraph in the above link.

> At runtime, the system ensures the best possible display on the current screen with the following procedure for any given resource:
>
> 1. The system uses the appropriate alternative resource
>      Based on the size and density of the current screen, the system uses any size- and density-specific resource provided in your application. For example, if the device has a high-density screen and the application requests a drawable resource, the system looks for a drawable resource directory that best matches the device configuration. Depending on the other alternative resources available, a resource directory with the hdpi qualifier (such as drawable-hdpi/) might be the best match, so the system uses the drawable resource from this directory.
> 2. If no matching resource is available, the system uses the default resource and scales it up or down as needed to match the current screen size and density
>      The "default" resources are those that are not tagged with a configuration qualifier. For example, the resources in drawable/ are the default drawable resources. The system assumes that default resources are designed for the baseline screen size and density, which is a normal screen size and a medium density. As such, the system scales default density resources up for high-density screens and down for low-density screens, as appropriate.
>
>    However, when the system is looking for a density-specific resource and does not find it in the density-specific directory, it won't always use the default resources. The system may instead use one of the other density-specific resources in order to provide better results when scaling. For example, when looking for a low-density resource and it is not available, the system prefers to scale-down the high-density version of the resource, because the system can easily scale a high-density resource down to low-density by a factor of 0.5, with fewer artifacts, compared to scaling a medium-density resource by a factor of 0.75.